# File being called by Ajax contains error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 pages, process page and form page.

So basically the form page consists of a lot of input text and once the user click the submit button, it runs the ajax call and call the process page. the process page requires user's credentials like id and password.

My ajax call basically success run, but the process page is not running. When there is no user logged in, the process page will output the undefined index message. In this case is the id or password, because basically there is no data passed(ID and Password) to the process page.

This is my ajax call function

```
function postTweet(){
$.ajax({
    url : 'blablabla',
    type : 'POST',
    data : blablabla,
    success: function() {
        div1.append("Success!");
 }})
 .fail(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

So basically after the non-loggedin user click the submit button, the Success message will still be displayed out, eventhough basically there is no process running in the process page.

What I want is, if the process basically is not running, I should prompt out a proper message.
Can someone help me please?

Any help given is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `success` function can handle arguments (look at ajax success [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

For example:

PHP File

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('test' => "hello world")); // echo any array data
exit(); // Stop php from processing more, you only want the json encoded data to be echoed
?>
```

Javascript File

```
...
dataType: 'json', // This is needed to convert the echoed php data to a json object
success: function (response) { // "response" will be the converted json object
    console.log(response);
},
...
```

The `console.log(response);` would look something like `Object {test: "hello world"}`

EDIT

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
if ( ! isset($username) ) {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => FALSE, 'message' => "Username is incorrect."));
}
...
exit();
?>
```

To alert the above error message in javascript:

```
...
success: function (response) {
    if (response.success) {
        alert('success!');
    } else {
        alert(response.message);
    }
},
...
```

Comment: so sir, the ajax call will only run if there is any json data type returned? Am I right?

Comment: If you have `dataType` set to `"json"` but do not echo json_encoded data (or have malformed json_encoded data) from your PHP then you would get a parser error. See [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to handle this issue.

1. if form page contain login credential input then you can validate login credentials are filled or not in java script and then call ajax process.
2. you can validate login credentials in ajax file using isset() method and if login credentials are not validated then you can send a simple message to ajax calls about login failed.

Comment: so i need to call another ajax file inside my process php file sir? and how can I connect that new ajax call to the previous ajax call?

Comment: No, you do not need to call another ajax file. What i want to say whether you handle login validation before calling ajax function or just modify process page code to handle login validation. That's it.

Comment: eventhough I put the validation code inside the process page, back to submit form, the ajax will still be considered as success right?

Comment: Yes, You have to put code with condition. if login of then do complete process else show login failed message.